# How many vectors are there in a two dimensional linear subspace of $(\mathbb{Z}_3)^6$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be a two dimensional linear subspace of $(\mathbb{Z}_3)^6$. How many vectors does $W$ contain?
My shot is that we have $3$ possible values for each of $6$ positions in a vector and we have $2$ of them. $W$ is a set: $$W=\{(x_1,...,x_6),(y_1,...,y_6)\}.$$ First vector can have $3^6$ possible permutations of coordinates. Same for the second one. Since the question didn't ask for all possible pairs, I conclude that $3^6$ is the answer. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb F_3^6$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_3^2$ and thus should have $3^2=9$ distinct vectors.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. You have 6 positions for 3 possible values.

Comment: If you could choose all coordinates in your subspace independently, you would get the 6-dimensional vector space...

Comment: Oh, I see. But how did you come up with $3^2$ specifically?

Comment: It seems like you tried to calculate how many subspaces of dimension 2 you can get. However even this calculation does seem to fail, since you don‘t take into account that the components you choose yield two linearly independent vectors...

Comment: Ok, I get it with the bijection now. Thanks.

Comment: Linear Algebra tells you that (by definition) a subspace of dimension 2 has to be isomorphic to $K^2$, where $K$ is your field. Note that an isomorphism of vector spaces is a bijection of sets in particular. The cardinality of $\mathbb F_3^2$ is $3^2$ since you can choose each component of a vector independently from each other out of the 3-element set $\mathbb F_3$